# Open Google Autofill Settings using Android Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-service

I am trying to develop an Autofill service for Android Devices using "Google AutoFill Services" that helps users, to redirect to the google autofill services page so that the user can enable/disable autofill services with click of a switch.

Using Android intent it redirects a user to enable a particular Service using this code.

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE)
intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOFILL)
```

[image]

**I wanted to redirect the user to this screen**

[image]
**How do I achieve this using Android Intent?**

I tried an other way by redirecting the user to the phone settings page using this intent but could not manage to get inside Google Settings.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOFILL)
```

[image]